# Printing a 2D character array read in from a file

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, formatting, output

Currently working on a school project involving a 2D char array representing a top-down view of a room, where 'W' = walls, 'F' = furniture, and ' ' = free space.  The array is meant to be read in from a file (contents of the file are below).

FILE:

```
2                                   
W   W   W   W   W   W   W   W   W   W
W       F       F   F               W
W       F       F   F       F   F   W
W       F       F   F       F   F   W
W       F       F   F       F   F   W
W       F       F   F       F   F   W
W       F       F   F       F   F   W
W       F       F   F       F   F   W
W       F                   F   F   W
W       F                   F   F   W
W           F               F   F   W
W   F       F               F   F   W
W   F       F               F   F   W
W                           F   F   W
W   W   W   W   W   W   W   W   W   W



W   W   W   W   W   W   W   W   W   W
W   F   F   F   F   F       F       W
W   F   F   F   F   F       F       W
W   F   F   F   F   F       F       W
W   F   F   F       F       F       W
W   F   F   F       F       F       W
W   F   F   F       F       F       W
W                   F               W
W                   F       F       W  
W   F   F   F               F       W
W   F   F   F   F           F       W
W   F   F   F   F           F       W
W   F   F   F   F   F       F       W
W   F   F   F   F   F       F       W
W   W   W   F   W   W   W   W   W   W
```

The '2' is irrelevant for now - it represents the number of room configurations.  I know that I will have to make a loop with that number later in the project.

Before I even begin the project, though, I wanted to print out my input to be sure that I am correctly reading in the file.  No matter what I try, I cant seem to get the correct configuration.  I have tried >> skipws as well as file.get() at multiple points in my code, and using these gives me different outputs but none match the original file.

My current code:

```
    int main()
{
    //Variables
    int i;
    int j;
    char room_array[room_height][room_width];
    char piece_of_room;
    int num_of_room_configurations;

//Create File, Open File, and Check File
ifstream room_file;
room_file.open("C:\\(path)\\rooms.txt"); 
if (room_file.fail())
    {
        cout << "Could not open file." << endl;
        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }

//Loop Control / Use File; The Number of Room Configs (will need to put this in a loop later)
room_file >> num_of_room_configurations;
cout << "Number of different room layouts: " << num_of_room_configurations << endl << endl;

//Create Room Array / Use File
for (i = 0; i < room_height; i++) //moves through rows
{
    cout << endl;
    for (j = 0; j < room_width; j++) //moves through columns
    {
        room_file >> piece_of_room; //reading in values from file
        room_array[i][j] = piece_of_room; 
    }
}

//Echo Original Room Layout
cout << endl << "ORIGINAL ARRAY:" << endl;
for (i = 0; i < room_height; i++) //moves through rows
{
    cout << endl;
    for (j = 0; j < room_width; j++) //moves through columns
    {
        cout << room_array[i][j]; //formatting
    }
}
cout << endl << endl;

system("pause");
    return 0;
```

I've taken out my attempts at including white spaces to make the code less complicated, so with this specific code I get this as an output:

[link to output screencap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HncB0.png)

Apologies for such a long question but I wanted to be sure I didn't leave out anything that could assist in somebody helping me.  I do not have a good understanding of C++ by any means so it is more than possible that I's missing something very basic.  Any help at all would be very appreciated, thank you in advance.

Also, this is my first post - if I've done anything incorrectly please let me know and I'll edit this if possible.

Answer (score 0):

While reading a file, you use >> operator to get a each character. But somehow it is not recognizing the space or skipping it. I'm not sure why. Instead of space if you try with other character say 'B', your code will work perfectly fine i believe.
You can refer to the below link how >> operator work on ifstream

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ifstream/

I would suggest you to use getline() function to read the input file, this would be easier and simpler. Your code may look like below (for example)

```
for (i = 0; i < room_height; i++) //moves through rows
{
    room_file.getline (&room_array[i][0],9); 
}
```